# PostgreSQL plperlu compilation error: ERROR: didn't get a CODE reference from compiling function

Tags: postgresql, plperlu

I have created language plperlu in Postgres 9.3 (OS - UBUNTU 12.04.5), using below command

CREATE LANGUAGE plperlu;

I wanted to call shell script from postgres function So I written below function using plperlu.

Below is function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tet_func (integer) RETURNS boolean
AS $$
$checkexitcode = system
("sh test_shell.sh");
if ($checkexitcode > 0) { return false; }
return true;
$$ LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

While compiling I am getting below error

ERROR:  didn't get a CODE reference from compiling function "tet_func"
CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/Perl function "tet_func"
********** Error **********

ERROR: didn't get a CODE reference from compiling function "tet_func"
SQL state: XX000
Context: compilation of PL/Perl function "tet_func"

Does anybody have idea why this error is occurring? Or anyone has other solution to call shell script from postgres function.

Comment: Are you sure that is valid perl? Does pl/perl define true/false for you, or have you done so somewhere and not shown it?

Comment: Hi Richard, How can I test it is valid perl or not? I have tested one perl script on ubuntu and it working fine.